# How to properly handle POST request from the server in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a payment system (gateway) in which the server sends the POST request to the API when the users request for payment using a cash card with PIN and SERIAL NO. I include the query-string in the return URL with the reference data for querying after the transaction for displaying the result.

The API returns the payment URL which is used to redirect users from my application to the payment gateway. Then the users are required to enter the cash card pin and serial number and the API then submit them. After checking the validity of the cash card entered the API will do two things:

1. It sends the POST request to the predefined callback URL with the result data such as status code, reference ID and amount of the cash card. This is for storing the payment result to the database and add the credit to the users based on the amount of the cash card returned.
2. It redirects the user back to the predefined return URL made when making a request for the first time, when we get the payment url, in which I query for the result recently stored in the database to display the payment result to the users.

The problem is that the application never accepts the POST request but gets "422: UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY".

This is the first POST data to the API and the redirection to the payment gateway:

```
def topup

    ref = 'ref'+Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')        

    params = {'app_code'=>'xxxx', 'secret'=>'xxxx', 'ref'=>ref, 'returnurl'=>'http://xxx.xxx.xxx/returnpath?=reference='+ref}
    api = 'http://api.xxx.xxx/topuprequest'
    raw = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(api), params)
    response = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw.body)

    # Redirect the user to the gateway using the URL returned from the API
    redirect_to response['paymentUrl']

end
```

This is the most important part which saves all returned data from the API to the database and updates the user credit, and is where the problem arises as the application rejects all requests to it and returns "422: Unprocessable Entity":

```
def callback

    # Retrieve POST data of the payment recently made from the API
    status = params[:status]
    amount = params[:amount]
    referenceId = params[:reference]

    # Create the transaction
    transaction = Transaction.new
    transaction.reference = referenceId
    transaction.amount = amount
    transaction.status = status
    transaction.save

    # Update the user credit with the amount returned (Just an example, in the production I query the userid from the transaction before an update)
    u = User.first
    u.update(credit:credit+amount.to_i)

    render nothing: true

end
```

This is the return URL which is defined in the first request. It queries the information recently stored in the database and displays it to the users. It uses the reference ID from the query string sent at the first step to search for the matched transaction, then queries for the status and the amount and finally displays the result to the user:

```
def returnpath
    # Retrieve the query string data
    ref = params[:ref]

    transaction = Transaction.where(ref = ?, ref).first
    status = transaction.status
    amount = transaction.amount

    message = 'You topup #{amount} to your account and the status is #{status}'

    render plain: message

end
```

The users request the payment and then get redirected to the gateway, Then enter the cash card PIN and SERIAL, then the system checks for the validity and its amount and sends the POST request as a callback to the application. Finally it redirects the users back to the return path that we initially define.

The problem is the callback, which is the POST request, is always rejected by the application. It responds with "422: Unprocessable Entity". I still can't figure it out why this happens.

Comment: are you only persisting the `amount`, or you have ommitted something on the `callback` method you have posted? what are you doing with `status` and `reference` parameters.

Comment: Please add how you are persisting your Transaction model to the database.

Comment: added the transaction saving so you can see the picture. @Optimus Pette

Comment: which model is failing to save, `transaction` or `user`?

Comment: I don't think it is a saving problem. It looks like there is no POST request recieved. So it returns 422.

Comment: error 422 is a response code for invalid data, please investigate the data you're trying to persist for both the user and the transaction and confirm that it is valid, the error is a response and this means your POST request is actually being received but its data is invalid.

Comment: Are you sure this method is not being run? Try putting a debugger statement in the method and see if it is hit.